# Do I need to use the approve function to transfer erc20 tokens from one address to another?

Tags: erc-20, transfer, erc-20-approve, transferfrom

I'm making an nft marketplace and I want the buyers to buy the nfts with WETH.

```js
    function createMarketSale(address nftContract, uint256 itemId)
        public
        nonReentrant
    {
        require(
            msg.sender != idToMarketItem[itemId].seller,
            "you cannot buy this item, this is your's"
        );

        uint256 price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;
        uint256 tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;

        require(WETH.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= price, "Insufficient funds");

        WETH.transferFrom(
            msg.sender,
            idToMarketItem[itemId].seller,
            price
        );

        IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
    }
```

Is this supposed to work?

Comment: if the sender is not the owner of the token then he need approve first. you cannot approve and transfer from in the same tx and the owner should by himself call the approve method in the token contract

Comment: okay, so how do I make that happen?

Comment: you tell the owner to go to the token contract and approve the tokens for you or your contract :) , you cannot do it for them

Comment: that's like very poor user experience, is this how platforms like opensea and rarible do it?

Comment: you are talking about erc20 (not NFT), right ? erc20 has that known negative issue

Comment: yup, i'm talking about transferring ERC20 tokens. If I want to buy a NFT listed on opensea for some WETH, what happens behind the scenes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132250/discussion-between-noob-rs-and-majd-tl).

Comment: I can’t join that chat now because I’m on my phone, but I’m sadly not familiar with opensea however they have a test version on one of the test nets where you can experiment :)